# How to determine the amount of idel time left in main thread for Unity before next frame?

Tags: unity, multithreading, timing

Hi I'm trying to improve a thread tool and would like to make a function which use the idle time before the next frame. So how can I determine  the time left?

Comment: This might be XY problem - why do you need time specifically on the main thread? Typically, low priority long running tasks run on background threads from thread pool.

Comment: @wondra I have a thread pool self implemented with priorities and for main thread activities I have time consumed. Some thing need to be main thread and are there for in need of knowing if there will be time left to execute. I hate frame skipping since it feels like you loose the connection to the game. I use this for my own variation of voxels (flow up terrain).